# How can I convert my halogen under cabinets dimmable lights to led if I do not know where the transformer is?

Tags: led, light, halogen

we can not find the transformer, I read that i can also replace the G4 lights directly?. I would really love some help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We aren't going to be able to find the transformer either; perhaps some pictures and diagrams might help us? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: What is the voltage of your G4 lamps? I have some 120v they would not require a transformer. A solid state dimmer would be all that is needed in that case.

Comment: The make/model of the light fixtures might help someone determine if you can safely replace the bulbs only or if more work will need to be done. Maybe with a couple of pics of the lights themselves someone might be able to give you an idea of where to look. Will VtC if no [edit] with additional info

Comment: What do you use for bulbs at the moment?

Comment: hi , the bulbs are G4 12 v 20 W.

Comment: light puck max 20 w 12 V JC Bi-pin. Everything is hardwire with a dimmer